# why my code run the first two element and stop in socket program?

Tags: python, sockets

first in the code i get the sever IP
then i make the tuple with the ip and port

then I create socket with AF_INET
in the terminal
code print the PORT and HOST and stop inter something does not end and what should i do to make hem run safe and complete
the code

```
from operator import imod
import socket
import os 


FORMAT = 'utf-8'
PORT = 9000
HEADER = 1024
SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())  # get the server IP
#SERVER_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
ADDR = (SERVER_HOST, PORT)  # tuple with the IP and PORT

# creating socket socket.AF_INET is the type, socket.SOCK_STREAM protocol method
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind(ADDR)  # bind the socket with to the address
server.listen(1)
print("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n")
print(f'[PORT]  Listening on port {PORT} ...')
print(f'[HOST]  Hosting on {SERVER_HOST} ...')


def readfile(myfile):
    # open file , r => read , b => byte format
    directory = os.getcwd()
    file =open(
        f"{directory}\\{myfile}",'rb')
    response = file.read()
    file.close()
    return response


while True:
    # Wait for client connections
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    print(f"[CLIENT IP]  {addr[0]}")
    print(f"[CLIENT PORT]  {addr[1]}")
    # Get the client request
    req = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    msg = req.split(' ')
    method, req_file = msg[0], msg[1]
    # Get the content
    print("[CLIENT IS REQUESTING]")
    print(f'[METHOD]    {method}')
    requested_file = req_file.lstrip('/')
    print(f"[REQUESTED FILE]    {requested_file}")
    print("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n")
    if(requested_file == '' or requested_file.lower() == 'en'):
        requested_file = 'index.html'
    elif(requested_file.lower() == 'ar'):
        requested_file = 'indexAR.html'

    try:

        header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n' #The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded
        Temporary_Redirect_Header = "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect\n".encode(
            FORMAT) #307 Temporary Redirect redirect status response code
        if(requested_file.endswith(".jpg")):
            response = readfile(requested_file)
            mimetype = 'image/jpeg'
        elif(requested_file.endswith(".png")):
            response = readfile(requested_file)
            mimetype = 'image/png'
        elif(requested_file.endswith(".css")):
            response = readfile(requested_file)
            mimetype = 'text/css'
        elif(requested_file.lower() == 'go'):
            conn.send(Temporary_Redirect_Header)
            conn.send("Location : https://www.google.com\n\n".encode(FORMAT))
        elif(requested_file.lower() == 'bzu'):
            conn.send(Temporary_Redirect_Header)
            conn.send("Location : https://www.birzeit.edu\n\n".encode(FORMAT))
        elif(requested_file.lower() == 'cnn'):
            conn.send(Temporary_Redirect_Header)
            conn.send("Location : https://edition.cnn.com/\n\n".encode(FORMAT))
        else:
            response = readfile(requested_file)
            mimetype = 'text/html'

        header += 'Content-Type: ' + str(mimetype) + '\n\n'

    except Exception as e:
        #404 Not Found response status code indicates that the server cannot find the requested resource
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n'
        # HTML FILE FOR HANDLING ERROR 
        response = '''
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
         <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Error</title>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/7.2.0/swiper-bundle.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
          </head>
          <body>
           <div class="welcome">
            <h2> <span style="color: red;"> The file is not found </h2>
              <h3> <span style="color: red;"> 404 Error </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="blog-slider">
           <div class="blog-slider__wrp swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- First slide -->
            <div class="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
             <!-- Slide content -->
             <div class="blog-slider__content">
             <div class="blog-slider__title">Malak Raddad</div>
             <!-- Second slide -->
             <div class="blog-slider__item swiper-slide">
             <!-- Slide content -->
           <div class="blog-slider__content">
          <div class="blog-slider__title">Leena Mouslit</div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </body>
        </html>
        '''

        response = response % (addr[0], addr[1]) # placing ip and port in html error file
        response = response.encode(FORMAT)# encode the html   


    final_response = header.encode(FORMAT)# encode the https header
    final_response += response # add the response to the header
    conn.sendall(final_response) # Send HTTP response to the client
    conn.close() # close the connection
```

and to the last what should i add to make him read the error html from file
the output is

```
[PORT]  Listening on port 9000 ...
[HOST]  Hosting on 192.168.56.1 ...
```

Comment: It's nice if you can make your question more focused. Anyway, my guess is that when you run this code, it then waits for a client to connect. In other words, this seems to be the server side of the code. You need the client side as well.

Comment: Where is sock.connect(host, port)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).